# Brew: get the cached file path for resource in a formula

Tags: curl, caching, homebrew

Is there a way to know where formula resources will be downloaded? I know you can use `brew --cache -s foo` to get the path where the formula's main program will be downloaded but it does not work for other files (resources). I need this since I have a very old Mac Pro whose curl is broken for some reason but wget works. I successfully managed to install simple packages using the cache technique but could not make it work for formulas with resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that by using the `-v` option on `brew upgrade` it gave me the output path to the resource files.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
brew install package-name -d
```

it will print cache name for resources used by package-name